# Как вставить в google docs картинку?

Tags: php, google-docs-api

Есть задача: в документе есть текст `{{печать}}`, нужно его удалить и на его место вставить изображение. Вопрос как это правильно реализовать?

Как я понимаю алгоритм действий следующий:
найти и заменить текст:

```
$requests = [];
$requests[] = [
    'replaceAllText' => [
        'replaceText' => '',
        'containsText' => [
            'text' => '{{печать}}',
            'matchCase' => true
        ]
    ],
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
$service->documents->batchUpdate(DOCUMENT_ID, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Потом вставить картинку:

```
$requests = array();
$requests[] = new Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
    'insertInlineImage' => array(
        'uri' => IMAGE_URL,
        'location' => array(
            'index' => 1, //Тут позиция которую нужно указать
        )
    )
));

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
$response = $docsService->documents->batchUpdate(DOCUMENT_ID, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Собственно вопрос: правильно ли я думаю и где взять данные о позиции заменяемого текста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось все проще, просто нужно было по капаться глубже в теме.
Решение:

```php
//Выводим тело документа
$document = $service->documents->get(DOCUMENT_ID, ['fields' => 'body']);
//Перебираем контентную составляющую документа
foreach($document->body->content as $content){
    if(!empty($content['paragraph'])){
        foreach($content['paragraph']['elements'] as $elements){
            //ищем наше значение
            $pos = strripos($elements['textRun']['content'], '{{печать}}');
            if($pos !== false){
                //Когда нашли, записываем его стартовый индекс впеременную
                $startIndex = $elements['startIndex'];
            }
        }
    }
}

//Проверка, нашлось ли значение
if(!empty($startIndex)){
    $requests = [];
    $requests[] = [
        'replaceAllText' => [
            'replaceText' => '',
            'containsText' => [
                'text' => '{{печать}}',
                'matchCase' => true
            ]
        ],
    ];

    //Заменяем слово пустотой
    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
    $service->documents->batchUpdate(DOCUMENT_ID, $batchUpdateRequest);

    $requests = [];
    $requests[] = new \Google_Service_Docs_Request(array(
        'insertInlineImage' => array(
            'uri' => 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=' . IMAGE_ID, //Вставляем картинку которая была загружена в гугл-диск
            'location' => array(
                'index' => $startIndex, //Наша стартовая позиция
            ),
            'objectSize' => array(
                'height' => array(
                    'magnitude' => 100,
                    'unit' => 'PT',
                ),
                'width' => array(
                    'magnitude' => 100,
                    'unit' => 'PT',
                ),
            )
        )
    ));

    //Вставляем изображение
    $batchUpdateRequest = new \Google_Service_Docs_BatchUpdateDocumentRequest(['requests' => $requests]);
    $service->documents->batchUpdate(DOCUMENT_ID, $batchUpdateRequest);
}
```